# JSON, newbie question

Tags: json

I want to link to a JSON object with `$.ajax({ url: ...`.

For starters, i dont know how to make the object. Defining it with javascript? Something like `var myObject = { 'color' : 'blue' };` and then saving it in to an .html file and adding to the url?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do what you are asking, but the file with the json data should just have this (later I will call it json.html):

```
{ 'color' : 'blue' }
```

and the jQuery on your other page should be:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'json.html',
    dateType: 'json'
    success: function ( data ) {
        // data is an object you can manipulate
    }
})
```

Comment: Hmm, im using http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp and i cant get it to work. What do I need to change?

Comment: @Johan:  jsonp is a little bit different than json.  It is intended for cross domain ajax calls (which usually aren't allowed) and it returns a callback function along with the data.  I don't think you need json for an autocomplete, just an old fashioned array.  I can't see how `{ 'color': 'blue' }` could be applied to an auto complete, please let me know and I will see if I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad. It would be best, if you read on of many introduction to JSON on the web. For one it's not clear what you mean with "link to a JSON object".

Keep in mind, that JSON has nothing to do with JavaScript really. It's just a data format to transport data - usually from a web server to a web client (=browser). It's just formated in a way, that is was simple to use JavaScript to read it.

Normally you would generate the JSON server side with PHP, ASP, or what ever you have or like (just as you would generate HTML pages server-side). It doesn't make much sense to have static JSON "files", because you wouldn't need to AJAX to read it and could just include the static data directly into your JavaScuipt.

Comment: They wont be static, they will be filled with product data from a database. I just want to get things working. Theyre gonna be generated through asp.net.